# Complexity of if statement

Tags: java, c, complexity-theory, time-complexity, space-complexity

I am wondering complexity of following if statement

```
if (isTrue()) //case 1
```

VS

```
if(isTrue()==true) //case 2
```

And isTrue defined as

```
boolean isTrue(){
//lots of calculation and return true false based on that.
 return output;
}
```

I was thinking, complexity of `if (isTrue())` is lower then `if(isTrue()==true)` because on case 2 require additional comparison for equals.

What about space complexity?

Any different thought?

Comment: How is there an additional comparison?

Comment: because compiler have to check function output with its right side value and then to test with if condition

Comment: @minhaz Most compilers would probably just optimize out those `if`s entirely, since `isTrue` will only ever return `true`.

Comment: I guess thats bad example, consider that function has one million lines of code.

Comment: @minhaz There's no difference between `if (foo)` and `if (foo == true)`. `if (foo)` still has to check `foo` for true.

Comment: @DaveNewton That's not correct. By the same logic you give, 'if (foo == true)' has to check 'foo == true' for being true. A compiler would be expected to optimise all the excess crud away but it's not the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

Both of them are same in speed/space. But second way is weird for C/C++ programmers.

*The different is, second way is just less readable.*

Comment: and weird for Java programmers too.

Answer (score 2):

They are equivalent. And when doing global optimizations condition is removed altogether.

Comment: if complier does the optimization that also increase processing right?

Answer (score 1):

The second case (checking for `==true`) can get problematic if you or someone else redefines the value of `true`.

Let's say that we have the following C code:

```
#define true 2

bool isEqual(int a, int b)
{
    return (a == b);
}

if (isEqual(5, 5)) {
    printf("isEqual #1\n");
}

if (isEqual(5, 5) == true) {
    printf("isEqual #2\n");
}
```

The output from this code will be

```
isEqual #1
```

So the shorter form where you leave out `==true` is preferable not only because it leads to less verbose code but also because you avoid potential problems like these.